# NDB Async access compatibility with Flask in Google App Engine GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, toplevel

I have been going through the google cloud NDB Async examles tutorials

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/async

> You can specify a whole WSGIApplication as ndb.toplevel. This makes
>   sure that each of the WSGIApplication's handlers waits for all async
>   requests before returning. (It does not "toplevel" all the
>   WSGIApplication's handlers.)

```
app = ndb.toplevel(webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MyRequestHandler)]))
```

Is this same functionality compatible with Flask? For example my code

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.update(DEBUG = not SERVER_ISPRODUCTION)
app = ndb.toplevel(app)
...
@app.route('/test')
def testBackfill():
```

Gives me error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27_experiment/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
   File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27_experiment/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
   File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27_experiment/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0]) 
    @app.route('/test')
 AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'route'
```

This error goes away when I move the toplevel back directly to the request handler.
I feel either flask doesn't work with this functionality, or I'm doing something wrong in how I'm using toplevel.
My intention is for each of my request handlers within my application to wait for all of my async Google DataStore calls to finish before exiting (I'm using yield statements and tasklets within my request handlers).

Answer (score 0):

The error is kind of expected: `app` is no longer the Flask app you created. I see 2 options to try:

- rename the top level app (you need to match the change in the `app.yaml` config file as well):

  ```
  app = Flask(__name__)
  app.config.update(DEBUG = not SERVER_ISPRODUCTION)
  my_app = ndb.toplevel(app)  # change .app -> .my_app app.yaml
  ```
- rename the flask app and all its references:

  ```
  flask_app = Flask(__name__)
  flask_app.config.update(DEBUG = not SERVER_ISPRODUCTION)
  app = ndb.toplevel(flask_app)
  ...
  @flask_app.route('/test')
  def testBackfill(): **strong text**
  ```

Note: I'm not a Flask user, this may fix the missing `route` attribute error but I don't know if it will ultimately make the top level stuff work. But I can't write this as a comment.

Comment: This works to solve the problem as described. The bigger question of whether toplevel works with flask still remains. When I run as described, it looks like my application is exiting without waiting for the async ndb calls to return on the yields. I'm using get_or_insert_async function, which doesn't seem to be persisting anything to the datastore as the application exits prior to response. In lieu of flask compatibility with ndb, which frameworks do you know work well with async ndb? Webapp2?

Comment: Yes, webapp2 works fine for me. But I only used `ndb.toplevel` at the handler's get/set methods level, not at the app level.